# How do I round the sum of two function returns that are stored within a variable?

Tags: javascript, math

I am using a function calculateTotal() for a form. Within this function is a variable that stores the sum of two other function returns. Depending on user input in the form, the sum can contain several decimal points. i.e. 76.6666666666. I would like to know if I can round this sum before it is displayed? I have tried Math.round(theWholeThing), doesn't work.
I don't know how I would round the number because it can change with user input to the form.
Same with parseint.

```
function calculateTotal()
{    
    var theWholeThing = areaTimesType() + getSetUp();       
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For grow space $"+theWholeThing + "\u00A0 \u00A0per month";
}
```

Comment: how do you want to show 76.666666666 to the user?

Comment: to two decimal points such as currency $ 76.66

Comment: `toFixed(2)` would solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `toFixed`

```
(76.6666666666).toFixed(); => 77
(76.6666666666).toFixed(1); => 76.7
```

Your code will look like this

```
function calculateTotal()
{    
    var theWholeThing = areaTimesType() + getSetUp();       
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For grow space $"+(theWholeThing).toFixed(2) + "\u00A0 \u00A0per month";
}
```

Comment: @Learn2Earn: Modified my answer

Comment: To me, this is a better answer.  Rounding to whole dollar amounts may be appropriate for some, but `toFixed()` is definitely the most straightforward way to round to an arbitrary amount of digits.

Comment: Vimsha. I like the method and results easier than (num*100) /100.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running Math.round()? Maybe you're not catching the result of the round() function. Try something like:

```
divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For grow space $"+ Math.round(theWholeThing) + "\u00A0 \u00A0per month";
```

Better yet, round the results when you declare theWholeThing:

```
var theWholeThing = Math.round(areaTimesType() + getSetUp());
```

Comment: var theWholeThing = Math.round(areaTimesType() + getSetUp());  Works beautifully. Great simple answer. Voted for this one. Thanks.

Comment: This could give slightly different results in different browsers.

Comment: Cheers @Learn2Earn, I wasn't aware of Fred's response regarding browser compatibility. And if you're looking for 2 decimal places for currency, perhaps the other answers suggesting toFixed() is more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one :

```
For 2 digit =  Math.round(num * 100) / 100
For 3 digit = Math.round(num* 1000)/1000
```

Detail for this function you can check in

[About Math.round](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml)

Comment: Math.Round can have odd results in some browsers

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, and you can also try this on

var num = 76.666666666;
var n=num.toFixed(2);

it will result = 76.67

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp